# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null and other null variables

Tags: javascript, html

Before I get started I just want to let you know I'm quite new to web development. I also want to keep this 100% javascript so no jquery or other languages for now.

The following code originates from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esa5hJegRfI

The error I'm getting is the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
>       at drawBarChart (script.js:58)
>       at script.js:66

This is the javascript:

```
var sampleData = [23,45,14,47,24,57,24,35];

function _div(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function drawBarChart(dataset, idOfContainer){

var chartContainer = _div(idOfContainer)

if(typeof(dataset) != "object"){
    return;
}

var heightOfContainer = chartContainer.scrollWidth;

var widthOfContainer = chartContainer.scrollHeight;

var widthOfBar = parseInt(widthOfContainer / dataset.length) - 2;

for(var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++){

    var divElement = document.createElement("div");

    divElement.setAttribute("class", "div2");

    divElement.style.marginLeft = parseInt(i * 2 + i * widthOfBar) + "px";
    divElement.style.height = parseInt(dataset[i]) + "px";
    divElement.style.width = parseInt(widthOfBar) + "px";
    divElement.style.top = (heightOfContainer - parseInt(dataset[i]) - 1) + "px";
    chartContainer.appendChild(divElement);

}
return false;
}



drawBarChart(sampleData, "div1");



console.log();
```

The variables heightOfContainer and widthOfContainer don't work because of the same error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollWidth' of null
>       at drawBarChart (script.js:42)
>       at script.js:66

or

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null
>       at drawBarChart (script.js:44)
>       at script.js:66

The last appendChild function does not seem to work and I have looked at other issues similar to this but can't seem to find one. 
The associated HTML code is just a div but if you want it here it is:

```
<div id="div1" ></div>
```

I know this error is quite personal and won't affect many others but I have asked elsewhere for help and I couldn't find out why it didn't work. Hope you can help and thanks for your time.

Comment: The error means that your `chartContainer` variable is `null`. That, in turn, means that your `_div()` function cannot find the element in the page.

Comment: If your script is placed in the `<head>` it runs before the document body is seen by the browser, so the code won't find it.

Comment: *"so no jquery or other languages"* - Note that jQuery isn't another language, it is a JavaScript library: that is, a collection of functions written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is loaded before the DOM is ready, so the selectors can't find those elements on the page.

You can put your JS at the bottom of the page so the DOM is fully loaded before the code is run and in turn your `div` element is available to the selector.

Here is a jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/poqefopuyu/edit?html,output