# 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null' when testing portalHost in Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing unit tests in our ***Angular Application*** using ***jest***. In this scenario, the content that must be shown in the **Main Tool Bar** from the **NavBar List** is projected using *PortalHost*. It is working fine in the application, but when I test it, it produces an error.

I have seen that there are many questions in SO that is related to this topic, but most of them are not in the same context as mine.

#### Error Stack

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

      22 | 
      23 |         // Attach portal to host
    > 24 |         this.portalHost.attach(this.portal);
         |                         ^
      25 |     }
      26 | 
      27 |     ngOnDestroy(): void {

      at node_modules/@angular/src/cdk/portal/dom-portal-outlet.ts:83:62
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at DomPortalOutlet.Object.<anonymous>.DomPortalOutlet.attachTemplatePortal (node_modules/@angular/src/cdk/portal/dom-portal-outlet.ts:83:23)
      at DomPortalOutlet.Object.<anonymous>.BasePortalOutlet.attach (node_modules/@angular/src/cdk/portal/portal.ts:215:19)
      at NavbarListGenComponent.ngAfterViewInit (src/app/main-toolbar/navbar-list-gen.component.ts:24:25)
      at callProviderLifecycles (../packages/core/src/view/provider.ts:569:14)
      at callElementProvidersLifecycles (../packages/core/src/view/provider.ts:541:7)
      at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (../packages/core/src/view/provider.ts:529:21)
      at checkAndUpdateView (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:375:3)
      at callViewAction (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:615:11)
      at execComponentViewsAction (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:559:7)
      at checkAndUpdateView (../packages/core/src/view/view.ts:370:3)
      at callWithDebugContext (../packages/core/src/view/services.ts:629:23)
      at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (../packages/core/src/view/services.ts:346:10)
      at ViewRef_.detectChanges (../packages/core/src/view/refs.ts:261:16)
      at ComponentFixture._tick (../../packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts:107:28)
      at ../../packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts:120:36
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:129:39)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:52)
      at Object.onInvoke (../packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts:273:25)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:52)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:43)
      at NgZone.run (../packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts:171:50)
      at ComponentFixture.detectChanges (../../packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts:120:19)
      at beforeEach (src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.spec.ts:25:17)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:129:39)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:52)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:43)
      at Object.testBody.length (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/zone-patch/index.js:52:27)
```

---

#### main-toolbar.component.html

```html
<div class="g-SiteHeader" *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)">

  <div id="navbarlist"></div>

<div>
```

---

#### navbar-list-gen.components.ts

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar-list',
    template: `
        <ng-template cdk-portal>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </ng-template>
    `,
})
export class NavbarListGenComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

    private portalHost: PortalHost;
    @ViewChild(CdkPortal) portal;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private injector: Injector, private appRef: ApplicationRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // Create a portalHost from a DOM element
        this.portalHost = new DomPortalHost(document.querySelector('#navbarlist'), this.componentFactoryResolver, this.appRef, this.injector);

        // Attach portal to host
        this.portalHost.attach(this.portal);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.portalHost.detach();
    }
}
```

---

I can't use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217040/8947616) as I'm not using plain JS and I'm not allowed to change the source code in order to write test cases. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30014117/8947616), I already have an element with the `id=navbarlist` which is rendered correctly in the app. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8670572/8947616), I think that the *DOM* element does not exist when the test is run, but can't seem to find a way to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have tried wrapping with `setTimeout` as mentioned [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/) and it worked. But is it the best and correct solution?

Comment: i've had this working with the setTimeout but i recently upgraded angular 8.1.2 to 9.0.0-next.4 and now i'm having this issue.  did you figure it out?

Comment: Sorry, no. I still use Angular 6/7 for my project and `setTimeout` is the only way I managed to fix this.

Comment: what did you wrapped exactly??

Comment: @RZ87 this was done quite long ago so I don't remember much, but afair, I wrapped the portal attachment part using ```setTimeout```